# Windows 10 restrict share to network interface

Tags: windows-10, sharing

I have a Windows 10 computer that is connected to two networks via two Ethernet cards. How to expose the shared folders to just one of these networks? The computer is not joined to any domain. There is just a workgroup in the network where I want to expose the shares.

Comment: Is the computer Domain joined, and is the network you want to expose the share on this network, or not?

Comment: @LPChip There is no domain involved. I have edited the question to include this detail. Thanks.